# Error attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android-studio

de antemano les cuento que es mi primera vez trabajando con android studio par un proyecto que estoy desarrollando así que les pido disculpas si el código no es lo mas optimo.

Tengo un código que envía un comando por bt a un microcontrolador para hacer una consulta.
Si ejecuto este proceso desde el onclick de un boton todo funciona bien, ahora si lo ejecuto al terminar el proceso de conexión con el modulo bluetooth la aplicacion crashea y me da error "attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference"

por aca les muestro el codigo.

```
buttonToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String cmdText = null;
            cmdText ="<Read>";
            connectedThread.write(cmdText);
        }
    });
```

Esta es la parte donde hago el llamado con el performclick() luego que termina la conexion con el modulo bluetooth.

```
handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case CONNECTING_STATUS:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case 1:
                            toolbar.setSubtitle("Connected to " + deviceName);
                            buttonConnect.setEnabled(true);
                            buttonToggle.setEnabled(true);
                            **buttonToggle.performClick();**(linea error)
                            break;
                        case -1:
                            toolbar.setSubtitle("Device fails to connect");
                            buttonConnect.setEnabled(true);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    String arduinoMsg = msg.obj.toString(); // Read message from Arduino
                             eContent.setText("E"+arduinoMsg);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Gracias de antemano.

Pd: este es el erro que me arroja al hacer el debug.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.emether, PID: 32187
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.emether.MainActivity$ConnectedThread.write(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.emether.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:149)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16221)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
    at com.emether.MainActivity$1.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:114)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: Buenas, Andrés, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Puedes editar la pregunta añadiendo el stack trace, la lista de errores completa? Y señala en el código que has pegado cuál es la linea que está generando el error.

Comment: Listo, ya añadí todo el error completo y señale la linea que da el problema.          Gracias